# Correct syntax for SQL Update function in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to use the SQL Update, SET and Where query using variables in excel VBA. I can create the string to update one query but for multiple columns it is proving more difficult. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

```
con.Execute "UPDATE [Maint_Record] SET [Completed_] ='" & strCompleted & "'" & "Where [ID] = '" & intID & "'"
```

The above line of code works well for the 'completed_' column. But when I need to update three more columns and the code below doesn't work!

```
con.Execute "UPDATE [Maint_Record] SET [Priority_] ='" & strPriority & "'," [Assigned_To] ='" & strAssignedTo & "', " [Comments_] ='" & strComments & "', " [Completed_] ='" & strCompleted & "'" & "Where [ID] = '" & intID & "';"
```

I am getting end of statement warnings and the like from Excel :-( Please can someone help? I'm so close to getting this working, but not close enough :-)

Comment: The query is easy in SQL (update Maint_Record set Priority_ ='Low', Assigned_To = 'Bob', Comments_ = 'All Done', Completed_ = 'Yes'
where ID='2';) But proving difficult to concatenate in Excel with variables :-( Please please help, it's driving me mad (Madder :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with your string - you have included extra quotes (`"`) where you don't want them.  See them highlighted below with `X`:

```
                 X
strPriority & "'," [Assigned_To] =

                    X
strAssignedTo & "', " [Comments_] =

                  X
strComments & "', " [Completed_] =
```

You need to take another look at this string and correct the issue with it, giving you something like:

```
con.Execute "UPDATE [Maint_Record] SET [Priority_] ='" & strPriority & "', [Assigned_To] ='" & strAssignedTo & "', [Comments_] ='" & strComments & "', [Completed_] ='" & strCompleted & "' Where [ID] = '" & intID & "';"
```

Your final `WHERE` statement is:

```
Where [ID] = '" & intID & "';"
```

If `intID` is a number (`int`) then you don't need the single-quotes:

```
Where [ID] = " & intID & ";"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, that's spot on, you're a star :-) thanks again.